# How to populate a dropdown using unselected options from other dropdowns?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I use JQuery Steps.In 1st and 2nd step, i have a dropdown with multiple select option.

```
<select name="numbers" id="numbers">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
```

in step2(same as step1 but with diff. purpose)

```
<select name="allocate_numbers" id="allocate_numbers">
  <option value="1">1</option>
   : : :
 </select>
```

now i have a 3rd dropdown in 3rd step.Here i want selectbox like..suppose user select `1,2` in step1, `3,4` in step2.

now,i want selectbox that contain only `5,6` in step3.
How to do that?

**side note:** I done validation to prevent duplicate entry for step1 and step2 dropdown.
means if user select 1,2 in step1 then he can not select 1,2 in step2. 
I don't find suitable title for my quetion so feel free to edit it.

Comment: Are all those three dropdowns on same page?

Comment: "now,i want" You want, that's ok but what have you tried to get it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated and better answer:**

The solution turns out to be rather simple. Find all unselected options in first dropdown and filter those that are not selected in other dropdowns. Add event delegation and the result is:

```
$(document).on("change", ".numbers", function () {
    $("#select1").empty();
    $(".numbers:eq(0) option:not(:selected)").filter(function () {
        return $(".numbers:gt(0) option[value=" + this.value + "]:selected").length === 0
    }).clone().appendTo("#select1");
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/q8gjE/2/)

**Original answer:**

This turned out to be a real brain twister. Basically you need to:

1. Prepare combined list of selected values
2. Iterate over options from both lists
3. Filter options that are not selected
4. Filter duplicates
5. Clone and append

Here is my go at it but there is probably a simpler solution:

```
$("#numbers, #allocate_numbers").on("change", function () {
    $("#select3").empty();
    var selectedValues = [],
        renderedValues = [];
    $.merge(selectedValues, $("#numbers").val() || []);
    $.merge(selectedValues, $("#allocate_numbers").val() || []);
    $("#numbers option, #allocate_numbers option").filter(function () {
        if ($.inArray(this.value, selectedValues) === -1) {
            if ($.inArray(this.value, renderedValues) === -1) {
                renderedValues.push(this.value);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }).clone().appendTo("#select3");
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/q8gjE/)

Comment: Cant you write $("#numbers option:not(:selected), #allocate_numbers option:not(:selected)").clone().appendTo("#select3");?

Comment: See revised answer (it turned out to be a nightmare).

Comment: What if one of dropdown is dynamically added? We get it's value using  `$('.numbers option:selected').each(function() {`. But how to use it?   (i got my answer but this one is for knowledge purpose.)

Comment: If the dropdow is dynamically added then `$("#numbers, #allocate_numbers").on()` won't work. You need to use delegation. Also the lines `$.merge` need to be changed to some kind of `.each()`.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, keep both dropdown values in 3rd dropdown and remove the values from 3rd, when it is selected in first and second dropdown. This is the easiest method.

Try jQuery code to remove and add options in dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

If one of the dropdown is  dynamically added then try this:

```
    $(document).on('change','.numbers, #allocate_numbers',function(){
    $("#select3").empty();
    var selectedValues = [],
        renderedValues = [];
            $('.numbers option:selected').each(function() {
              $.merge(selectedValues, $(this).val() || []);
            });
    $.merge(selectedValues, $("#allocate_numbers").val() || []);
    $(".numbers option, #allocate_numbers option").filter(function () {
        if ($.inArray(this.value, selectedValues) === -1) {
            if ($.inArray(this.value, renderedValues) === -1) {
                renderedValues.push(this.value);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }).clone().appendTo("#select3");
});
```